# how to build a variable to summarized muti variables

Tags: r, paste, gsub

I have a data looks like this:
[image]

The sample data can be get by following codes:

```
ID<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
Days<-c(-5,1,18,30,1,8,16,1,8,6,-6,1,7,15)
Event_P<-c("","","P","","","","P","","","P","","","P","P")
Event_N<-c("","","","","N","","N","","","N","N","","N","N")
Event_C<-c("C","","C","","","","C","","","C","","","","")

Sample.data <- data.frame(ID, Days, Event_P, Event_N,Event_C)
```

I want to build a variable "Event" to capture all events. The final results will look like this:

[image]

What should I do? I would like to know as many ways as possible.  Thanks.

Comment: `within(Sample.data, Event <- paste(EventP, Event_N, Event_C, sep = "/"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be using `apply()` like this. The suggestion from @AllanCameron is also a great choice. Here the code as option for you:

```
#Vectors
ID<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
Days<-c(-5,1,18,30,1,8,16,1,8,6,-6,1,7,15)
Event_P<-c("","","P","","","","P","","","P","","","P","P")
Event_N<-c("","","","","N","","N","","","N","N","","N","N")
Event_C<-c("C","","C","","","","C","","","C","","","","")
#Data
Sample.data <- data.frame(ID, Days, Event_P, Event_N,Event_C,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Option 1
index <- which(grepl('Event',names(Sample.data)))
Sample.data$Event <- apply(Sample.data[,index],1,function(x) paste0(x[x!=''],collapse='/'))
```

Output:

```
   ID Days Event_P Event_N Event_C Event
1   1   -5                       C     C
2   1    1                              
3   1   18       P               C   P/C
4   1   30                              
5   2    1               N             N
6   2    8                              
7   2   16       P       N       C P/N/C
8   3    1                              
9   3    8                              
10  3    6       P       N       C P/N/C
11  4   -6               N             N
12  4    1                              
13  4    7       P       N           P/N
14  4   15       P       N           P/N
```

Comment: This is very clever way. Never thought of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Duck's answer is very good, but you mentioned you want as many ways as possible so here are two more ways:

You could also use tidyverse's `mutate` and base r's `interaction` to combine the columns then use `gsub` to clear out all the unnecessary things:

```r
ID<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
Days<-c(-5,1,18,30,1,8,16,1,8,6,-6,1,7,15)
Event_P<-c("","","P","","","","P","","","P","","","P","P")
Event_N<-c("","","","","N","","N","","","N","N","","N","N")
Event_C<-c("C","","C","","","","C","","","C","","","","")

Sample.data <- data.frame(ID, Days, Event_P, Event_N,Event_C)

library(tidyverse)

Sample.data %>% 
  mutate(Event = paste(Event_P, Event_N, Event_C, sep='/'),
         Event = gsub('^/|^//|/$|//$', '', Event),
         Event = gsub('//', '/', Event))
#>    ID Days Event_P Event_N Event_C Event
#> 1   1   -5                       C     C
#> 2   1    1                              
#> 3   1   18       P               C   P/C
#> 4   1   30                              
#> 5   2    1               N             N
#> 6   2    8                              
#> 7   2   16       P       N       C P/N/C
#> 8   3    1                              
#> 9   3    8                              
#> 10  3    6       P       N       C P/N/C
#> 11  4   -6               N             N
#> 12  4    1                              
#> 13  4    7       P       N           P/N
#> 14  4   15       P       N           P/N

Sample.data$Event <- 
  interaction(Sample.data$Event_P, Sample.data$Event_N, Sample.data$Event_C, sep = '/') %>% 
  gsub('^/|^//|/$|//$', '', .) %>% 
  gsub('//', '/', .)

Sample.data
#>    ID Days Event_P Event_N Event_C Event
#> 1   1   -5                       C     C
#> 2   1    1                              
#> 3   1   18       P               C   P/C
#> 4   1   30                              
#> 5   2    1               N             N
#> 6   2    8                              
#> 7   2   16       P       N       C P/N/C
#> 8   3    1                              
#> 9   3    8                              
#> 10  3    6       P       N       C P/N/C
#> 11  4   -6               N             N
#> 12  4    1                              
#> 13  4    7       P       N           P/N
#> 14  4   15       P       N           P/N
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

What inside the `gsub(^/|^//|/$|//$)` does is

`^/|^//`: Take out all `/` or `//` that start the string

`/$|//$`: Take out all `/` or `//` that end the string

Comment: One question sort of relate to this. If I use case_when,statement. If no cases match, NA is returned. Is it possible for me to get "" instead. If so, How to do it? I am building var for Event_P, etc,  with case_when, and it gave me NA so the data looks different.